# error in displaying a 3-D Plot in matlab

Tags: matlab

I wanted to draw the following function in matlab:
   `f(x,y)  = sqrt(1-x^2-4y^2)    ,(if  (x^2+4*y^2) <=1 )`

```
        =  0                  ,otherwise.
```

I wrote the following code in matlab:

```
  x=0:0.1:10;  
  y=0:0.1:10;
  z=x.^2+4*y.^2;
  if (z <=1)
   surf(x,y,z);

  else
   surf(x,y,0);
  end
```

but the following error is displayed:
      `surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and columns (Z) must be the same as length (X)`
How shall I avoid this error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should really check what you are doing... line by line

```
x = 0:0.1:10; % define x-array 1x101
y = 0:0.1:10; % define y-array 1x101
z = x.^2+4*y.^2; % define z-array 1x101
```

However, `surf` needs a matrix as input for `z` therefore the syntax as you use it here is incorrect.

Instead, create a x-grid and y-grid:

```
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y); % both being 101x101 matrices

zCheck = xx.^2+4*yy.^2; % 101x101
zz     = sqrt(1-xx.^2-4*y.^2)
```

Concerning the if statement, you better change the values before plotting:

```
zz(zCheck > 1) = 0; % replace the values larger than 1 by zero (use logical indexing)

figure(100);
surf(x, y, zz);
```

Comment: Being new to matlab,I really don't understand why we create x-grid and y-grid here....I didn't get it...can you please help with this..

Comment: @coool. It is not Matlab specific. A `surface` have to be defined as a value Z versus a 2D plane of coordinates. You cannot define a surface on a `line`. Have a look at the [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) documentation, and you can also read about [Creating Mesh and Surface Plots](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/learn_matlab/creating-mesh-and-surface-plots.html)

Comment: @coool for a surface plot you want to calculate the value for z on each (x,y) coordinate. This means z will be matrix. In order to do this using element-wise multiplication `.*` you need to have matrices for x,y. `meshgrid` creates matrices for both your `x` and `y` vectors. Actually, it just repeats the x vector in y direction and vice-versa. Please have a look at the link @Hoki mentioned in the comments.